# What's the idea behind 94% scale factor of the sans serif in NewTX?

Tags: fontsize, height, newtx

Feeding

```
\documentclass{standalone}% 2018/03/26 v1.3a
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% 2021/04/29 v2.0v
\usepackage[helvratio=.9]{newtxtext}% 2022/02/28 v1.71
\begin{document}
X\textsf{X}x\textsf{x}
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` yields [image: good output].
Here, the sizes of the serif and sans-serif letters roughly match. According to the NewTX documentation, 90% scaling was the default prior to version 1.7.  Let's take a look at the default now:

```
\documentclass{standalone}% 2018/03/26 v1.3a
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% 2021/04/29 v2.0v
\usepackage{newtxtext}% 2022/02/28 v1.71
\begin{document}
X\textsf{X}x\textsf{x}
\end{document}
```

results in [image: bad output].  Clearly, the sans font got taller at least as far as the heights of X and x are concerned. The serif and sans serif fonts don't go that well together in a single sentence any longer. Why was the default changed? What's the point?

I have informed the NewTX maintainer. (However, I received no reply to my prior messages from two months ago, so whoever wishes to ping him, please feel free…)

Comment: The point is that normally you don't mix serif and sans serif in the same sentence. If you need to, you can use the scaling option. Apparently the maintainer of NewTX changed his mind about the right default scaling factor, probably thinking to titles in sans serif. But this question should be asked to the maintainer, we can only have opinions on it.

Comment: @egreg You sometimes typeset identifiers (from maths, modeling, specification, or programming) in sans serif while the main text is in serif. This results in sentences like “Each subsystem has a name; therefore, the diagram contains the nodes Sender, Medium1, Medium2, and Receiver.”, where “Sender”, “Medium1”, “Medium2”, and “Receiver” are typeset in sans serif and the main text in serif. So, in such texts, you mix sans serif and serif pretty often. In any case, thanks for your opinion!

Comment: The optimal scaling factor should depend on whether you are aiming to equate the x-heights or the uppercase letters' heights of the Times Roman (clone) and Helvetica (clone) fonts. E.g., to match the x-heights *exactly*, one should use a scaling factor of 0.859; and to match the uppercase heights exactly, one should use a factor of 0.907. Since the author/maintainer of the `newtxtext` packages chose a scaling factor of 0.90, it would appear that he gave more weight to matching the heights of the two fonts' uppercase letters.

Comment: @Mico I got it, but that's not the point. The maintainer chose 0.9 earlier. Now he abandonded 0.9 in favor of 0.94 without a compelling reason in my view.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Isn’t it what I wrote? If you do need to mix, apply the scaling option that fits yout taste. Or even an altogether different sans serif font.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask this to us. Contact the maintainer, he is the only one who can say if it is bug or something done by purpose or necessity. Beside this: version 1.7 made lots of changes to adapt the package to all engines. And if you run e.g. with lualatex you will see that there the lowercase x matches by default.

Comment: @egreg I understood you; I didn't comment on it. I wrote “in MY view”. This is because in MY document (with svmono class), sans serif is not used anywhere except explicit `\mathsf` or `\textsf` (in particular, my titles are typeset using a serif font).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Not quite: compiled with `lualatex`, the sans-serif x is a little bit smaller than the serif x, and the sans-serif X is clearly bigger than the serif X; cf. https://i.imgur.com/jFIpue2.png .  IMHO, with `lualatex` it's pointless to use NewTX anyway because you could switch to better/richer OTF fonts as well.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Though I informed the NewTX maintainer on this matter now, I have to say that I received no reply to my prior e-mails to him on a different matter from two months ago. If you or anyone else wish to ping him, please feel free…

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "richer OTF fonts", newtx uses otf fonts with lualatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh; I did not know that. I guess meant the direct interface commands `\setmainfont`, `\babelfont`, `\setsansfont`, `\setmonofont`, and `\setmathfont` with tons of options.